# v-for to loop thru an exernal array based on a selector

Tags: vue.js, v-for

JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/529272/

I have 2 arrays:

#### [#1] Price list

```json
[
  {
    "n_bubble": "2",
    "size_1": "40.00",
    "size_2": "72.00",
    "size_3": "112.00"
  },
  {
    "n_bubble": "5",
    "size_1": "65.00",
    "size_2": "98.00",
    "size_3": "144.00"
  },
  {
    "n_bubble": "10",
    "size_1": "90.00",
    "size_2": "138.00",
    "size_3": "183.00"
  }
  ...
]
```

#### [#2] Parts

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "bubble_size": "1",
    "n_bubble": "0",
    "price": "0",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "bubble_size": "2",
    "n_bubble": "7",
    "price": "0",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "bubble_size": "1",
    "n_bubble": "0",
    "prezzo": "0",
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "bubble_size": "1",
    "n_bubble": "0",
    "prezzo": "0",
  }
]
```

I'm looping thru "parts" and based off of a radio button connected to `bubble_size` I have to select `n_bubble` from  `price list` array and select the matching size:

```html
<div v-for="(part, index) in parts" :key="part.id">
    <label>Bubble size</label><br>

    <label>1 
    <input type="radio" v-model="part.bubble_size" :checked="part.bubble_size == 1" value="1" :name="'bubble_size['+index+']'" /></label>

    <label>2 <input type="radio" v-model="part.bubble_size" :checked="part.bubble_size == 2" value="2" :name="'bubble_size['+index+']'" /></label>

    <label>3 <input type="radio" v-model="part.bubble_size" :checked="part.bubble_size == 3" value="3" :name="'bubble_size['+index+']'" /></label><br>

    <label>Bubble number <input type="number" min="0" v-model.number="part.n_bubble" /></label><br>

    <label for="">Price <input type="number" min="0" v-model.number="price_list[0]['size_'+part.bubble_size]" /></label>
    <br><br>
</div>
```

I'm trying to work on this:

```html
<input v-model.number="price_list[0]['size_'+part.bubble_size]" type="number" />
```

I temporarily placed a `0` index as I don't have a clue on how to select the matching number based on `pricelist.n_bubble`. I need to select the closest `less than` based on `parts.n_bubble`

#### Expected result:

If I select radio `bubble_size => 2` and `n_bubble => 7`, `price` should set at `98` as it should take the second array in `price list`, because `7` less than `n_bubble 10`:

```js
{
 "n_bubble": "5",
 "size_1": "65.00",
 "size_2": "98.00", // <---- this one
 "size_3": "144.00"
},
```

Comment: Is the price-list array in order of `n_bubble`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use method call that would take the bubble number from input and return the index of lesser or equal number. The method call would replace the hard coded value. It would become as below:

```
v-model.number="price_list[findPriceIndex(part.n_bubble)]['size_'+part.bubble_size]"
```

I have forked above jsfiddle and updated it to get the dynamic price per your logic using a computed property and a method. Below is the updated jsfiddle. This method may not be as efficient but just a quick example.

https://jsfiddle.net/gowrimr/4qrws8kj/5/